# Why does hair thicken and become more rough after a razor shave but not after one using a trimmer?

Tags: human-biology, hair

If a razor cuts only the hair, then how does hair thicken and become more rough with a razor shave and not after one using a trimmer? If both are used for hair removal, why is there a difference in hair growth?

I have been using a trimmer for 1 year, but the growth of hair remained unchanged.  When I started shaving with a razor, the hair growth thickened.

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5873922/10-stubborn-body-myths-that-just-wont-die-debunked-by-science, and under skin and hair in this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_misconceptions

Comment: This is a myth and your evidence is purely anecdotal - voting to close as not on topic. Might suit skeptics.se

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on skeptics

Comment: May I ask how this belongs in Skeptics? It is a question seemingly based in biology that has a biological answer...

Comment: @SamuelBarnett Because the question is based on a flawed premise. It's a myth, a wives tale, that hair does this. Before it is possible to answer a question of why something happens we should first have reason to believe it happens. We know that *it* doesn't so there is no question of why *it* does happen.

Comment: @GriffinEvo Are you saying that the removal of the tapered end is a misconception? and that the "truth" behind the misconception is a misconception itself? If so can you provide some evidence for it? 

Also if (the previous is not the case) people ask a question with a flawed logic or understanding behind it surely we should reply with a scientific answer not direct their question to the sceptics site even if we know the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hair does not grow back thicker when it is cut. This is somewhat of an optical illusion because when you shave with a razor it leaves the top of the hair flat rather than pointed so it appears thicker. For instance see this picture:

[image: Hair being cut]

As you can see the hair is tapered at the top and when cut loses this taper to leave a large cross-sectional area. I would say that for your question with with the trimmer that it is probably cutting the hair further up the taper where the hair is 'thinner' to begin with. A razor cuts closer to the base and thus gives a thicker appearance.

Evidence: http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-if-you-shave-or-wax-your-hair-will-come-back-thicker/

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0190962299701817

Comment: could you provide a source for A) a hair being tapered as in the diagram, and B) cutting it flat makes it appear thicker then when tapered.

Comment: could you summarise the important findings of the paper - its behind a paywall

Comment: @GriffinEvo I am sorry my institution automatically passes me through paywalls so I didn't realise. I will sum it up in the morning as it is getting quite late here.